# Program that checks if HTML tags are balanced python

Tags: python, oop, stack

I need to make a function that uses a stack to see if an html file has opening and closing tags balanced. The problem lets you assume that the html appears line by line without having to worry about indents. My program below works when I unbalance the closing tags, such as < html >>, and that is all the question asks for, but I am trying to edit my function so it would see unbalanced html opening tags. Things like < html >> are noticed by my function, but things like << html > are not noticed. I was thinking I could add another statement to my function like 
   "if ch == '<' and not stack.is_empty():
   return False"
but I am not sure where I would place that in the function.

```
class Stack:
""" Last in first out"""
def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
def is_empty(self):
    return self.items == []
def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items - 1)]
def push(self,item):
    return self.items.append(item)
def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()
def size(self):
    return len(self.items)

def HTMLCheck(newfile):
    # How to see if << is covered
    with open(newfile) as file:
        stack = Stack()
        list1 = list()
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            list1.append(line)
        index = 0
        while index < len(list1):
            for ch in list1[index]:
                if ch == '<':
                    stack.push(ch)
                elif ch == '>':
                    if stack.is_empty():
                        return False
                    else:
                        stack.pop()
            index += 1

        return True


print(HTMLCheck('HW5.txt'))
```

Comment: Can we have a version of your code that doesn't read the input from a file, i.e. a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def HTMLCheck(newfile):
    # How to see if << is covered
    with open(newfile) as file:
        stack = Stack()
        list1 = list()
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            list1.append(line)
        index = 0
        while index < len(list1):
            for ch in list1[index]:
                if ch == '<':
                    stack.push(ch)
                elif ch == '>':
                    if stack.is_empty():
                        return False
                    else:
                        stack.pop()
            index += 1

        return stack.is_empty() # if the stack is not empty then it was not balanced ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. I improved the algorithm a little bit and also check the full name of the tag.

```
import re

def tagChecker(symbolString):
    s = Stack()
    pattern = re.compile('<.*?>')
    pattern_close = re.compile('</.*?>')
    tag_list = re.findall(pattern, html_str)
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(tag_list) and balanced:
        tag = tag_list[index]
        if not pattern_close.match(tag):
            s.push(tag)
        else:
            if s.isEmpty() or str.replace(tag, '/', '') != s.peek():
    # s.peek() - function, which returns top of the stack without removing
                balanced = False
            else:                
                s.pop()

        index = index + 1

    if balanced and s.isEmpty():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```